# Can i delete this file "html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" from my website?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have this code in my website and i was wondering if there's any use of it?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> <![endif]-->
```

Here is my website https://www.sydneycityremovalists.com.au/

Comment: We can't answer that for you imo.

Comment: This code loads whats called a "polyfill" if the views browser is an `internet explorer` older than version 9. A polyfill recreates the abilities of modern browsers in older browsers, so if either **A.** You don't use any modern browser abilities or **B.** Your clients won't be using older Internet Explorers, then you can delete this snippet safely. If any of the aforementioned or in doubt: best to keep it and get a professional to look at the code. Going through an entire website and user base is too much to ask for on StackOverflow.

Comment: thanks @EmilS.Jørgensen for the comment, is the a late version of this code?

Comment: I believe this github page contains the newest version: https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv#manual-installation 
Remember to take a back-up if you are going to edit your code. Also it might be a good idea to keep a local copy of the file on your own server, in case the url address changes in the future.

Comment: is this the one? '<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->' please help @EmilS.Jørgensen

Comment: @R.Shamon Almost. That particular link assumes that another program called `bower` has made the installation for you. The file you want lies in `master/dist/` and is called `html5shiv.min.js`. You can access it directly from github via: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/master/dist/html5shiv.min.js 
I would recommend that you get a local version of the file and refer to that, but you could solve the problem with:
`<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/master/dist/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->`

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen Absolutely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A polyfill, or polyfiller, is a piece of code (or plugin) that provides the technology that you, the developer, expect the browser to provide natively. Flattening the API landscape if you will.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/master/dist/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

Here's an example: `sessionStorage` is available in all the latest browsers (IE8 and upwards) but isn't in IE7 and below.A polyfill can be used to plug the support for older browsers that don't provide `sessionStorage`.

Don't remove if you want to make it useful to your lower version User Agent(Browser).In your case,Js is load while IE browser is lower then version 9.0.

Comment: The link appears to be broken in your answer. http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/ redirects to the GitHub page, so you can create a new link to that.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen please check again and edit if required

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen Thanks for make it more accurate.